# Permission denied to my own GitHub repo

Tags: git, github

I am travelling and do not have my normal laptop. I need to create a new project and push it to my GitHub as a new repo. My friend, who owns this laptop (that I'm writing this question from) also does a lot of stuff on GitHub. So I created the project locally, and then logged into GitHub and created the remote repo. GitHub wants me to run the following typical commands for all new repos:

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/mygithubuser/example-app.git
git push -u origin master
```

When I went to go do the `git push -u origin master`, I am getting the following error:

```
remote: Permission to mygithubuser/example-app.git denied to other-user.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/mygithubuser/example-app.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

...where `other-user` is my friend's GitHub username (after all, I'm using his laptop). So I looked up the typical fix and tried running:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/mygithubuser/example-app.git
```

Git didn't complain, so then I tried re-running:

```
git push -u origin master
```

...but am getting the same '403' error. Any ideas where I'm going awry and what the fix here is? Ideally there is some magic command that will ask me to authenticate as my typical user?

Comment: Can temporary add the ssh pub key to you keys on github, then remove it when you give a laptop back? sounds like the easiest option to me.

Comment: Thanks @speedingeer (+1) - how would this work? Where would I find the SSH pub key being used? `~/.ssh/known_hosts` doesn't contain any GitHub references in it...

Comment: github has excellent documentation for using ssh keys.
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/

Comment: But he is using https which doesn't use the ssh keys

Comment: Thanks @speedingeer (again +1), so to confirm: (1) generate SSH keys while signed in as `mygithubuser`. (2) Add the public key to my friend's laptops key chain, (3) Do the push, and (4) the commit will show up as being pushed by `mygithubuser`? How does it authenticate me? And I'm fine using SSH, the only thing things that matter here are that I am able to push to my repo and that the push shows up as having come from me (`mygithubuser`).

Comment: generate ssh on your laptop, next get public key and add it your github account. github will recognise your this laptop as "your laptop" so yes it will be mygithubuser.

Comment: Thanks, so how does the `git push -u origin master` command change now that I'm using an SSH key? or does it? if it doesn't change then what's happening under the hood? is git just looking for a valid private key in the local key chain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configure who have access to your repo in Settings/Collaborators, you need to login as yourself: https://github.com/mygithubuser/example-app/settings/collaboration

If you want the commit author to be different than the user that is committing you can use `--author`:

```
git commit --author="John Doe <john@doe.org>"
```

The example comes from the [excellent git tutorial from Tower](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email).

With this the committer will be `other-user` and the author will be the one you specify. Make sure you are using the correct name/email you have on your user.

Comment: Thanks @Felipe Cypriano (+1) - if my typical Github user is `mygithubuser`,  and I follow your suggestion above, then would the push show that `mygithubuser` pushed the change, or that `other-suer` pushed the change? I need it to be from me (`mygithubuser`)!

Comment: My suggestion will give access to `other-user`, so if you push with him it will show as him. So if you don't want to give `other-user` commit access, don't do what I said.

Comment: @smeeb I added some more information on how you can use `other-user` to submit the commit but put yourself as the author.

Comment: Thanks @Felipe but thats not what I need :-/. I guess I just don't understand why I can't push the change with specific user/password combo...

Comment: Since you are using https you should be able to push the changes if your username/password credentials from any computer, but not with `other-user`'s (unless you give him access).

Comment: Thanks again @Felipe, what if I went with an SSH key approach as speedinger has suggested? Can you see my last question under his comments (above), I have the same question for you! That is, if I generate an SSH key, how do I push my changes? Is it the same command as `git push -u origin master`? How would Git know who I am when I run that?

Comment: Yes, all commands are the same. You just need to use ssh as the origin url instead of https. `git@github.com:mygithubuser/example-app.git`

Answer (score 1):

For The access Denied Issues And git username , password

I had this problem too but managed to solve it, the error is that ur computer has saved a git username and password so if you shift to another account the error 403 will appear. Below is the solution
For Windows you can find the keys here:

control panel > user accounts > credential manager > Windows credentials > Generic credentials

Next remove the Github keys.

Answer (score 0):

Just give your friend push rights for your repository.
Author and Committer will still be you.
It doesn't really matter who did the actual push.
Who pushes does not modify the commits metadata in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
[press return]
```

After, `push -u origin master`